# Issue with Publishing NPM Package (org.couchdb.user:USERNAME' is not in the npm registry)

Tags: npm, package, libraries, npm-publish

**Issue:**

I'm trying to publish my npm package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker` and it's coming up with the error. It's been 9 months since I last have made a publish and I just updated a ton of code and files. I also set the publishing from NPM to GitHub, but **I think I reverted those changes?**

**Question:**

1. Why am I getting the errors below?
2. How can I make sure that the npm package is published to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker`?

**Errors:**

```
org.couchdb.user:jefelewis' is not in the npm registry.

This package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

```js
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

**Process:**

1. `npm login`
2. **Enter login info** (Username: `jefelewis`)
3. `org.couchdb.user:jefelewis` is not in the npm registry.
4. The issue is that my username is `jefelewis` ([https://www.npmjs.com/~jefelewis](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Ejefelewis))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
This was fixed by using `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` in the terminal